# "Boss...here's why we need teams" feature needed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the page introducing teams, it would be clever or nice to have a link that gives my boss the reasons (not so technical) of why Teams will help us out (fork the cash because I am liking this).

I know it's not really expensive (I could foot the $10.00 a month myself) but the questions I keep getting is we have Confluence, we have Jira, we have HipChat, **why do we need teams**? Be nice to have this link give my boss the reasons - kind of like what Microsoft does when you want to attend a training and need to convince the powers at the top.

I actually stumbled upon what Joel himself wrote - https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/05/03/announcing-stack-overflow-for-teams/

Maybe this could be incorporated on the *BossReasonsForPurchasingSOTeam*s page? Sure I could've linked the boss to Joel's explanation but it was too late!

PS: We haven't bought teams yet but I am hoping to have some answer fairly soon. Hell for all the jobs bugs I discovered and reported on SO Jobs it would've been a real nice incentive to get a teams token.

Comment: I'd recommend not recommending a tool that you can't realistically pitch or justify to your boss.  Not every organization has a need for something like this, which is fine.  It's worse if this turns into a sales pitch for something that is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: I don't think its unnecessary I think it would help flush out the details of why we need it.  Too much knowledge is stuck in our brains...a Q&A would flush that out and put it in a system that simply works with built in search capability.  This is the primary reason I don't want to put Q&A in Confluence or even Jira.  Sometimes pitching stuff to people who don't yet see the benefit can be difficult.  FYI I'm pitching to a VP who probably doesn't have the time to tell the difference between said systems.

Comment: I suppose I'm dancing around the question.  Do _you_ personally see the benefit for your org?  If you do, can you condense it into five or six bullet points with _maybe_ a disambiguation or two on why it's different from what y'all already use?  If you can do that I'm not sure how Stack Overflow could do it *better*....

Comment: @Makoto - Well its not for me only...Sure only now can I do that (as I did that already) I am asking in general it would be nice such that at the end of the teams introduction page there was a nice shiny link (doesnt have to be shiny) that said `Click here to convince the boss...` and the link would give you standard points of why it could be beneficial.  It could even include snippets of what Joel posted.  Longest sentence ever...

Comment: Golden rule is to never ask the boss to spend fifty bucks of his time to handle a ten dollar purchase.  This does seem to be aimed at the "shucks, I'll do it myself" price-point.  Ask for multi-month/year quotes.

Comment: @HansPassant - This is the point we would be paying annually.

Comment: Hey - please don't use other people's email addresses to try to join teams. It doesn't work, but it's annoying for whoever owns the email address you're trying to pass off.

Comment: Shog fix it. I posted the bug

Comment: @JonH it's not a bug. You can visit `<something>.slack.com` and do the same thing...

Comment: Dont make teams so easily discoverable it doesnt make sense. It is a bug!

Comment: Why should i be able to join fogcreek?

Comment: @JonH seriously? you can't *join* fogcreek, you need a valid email address to do so. You're conflating two different things; the discoverability (a problem with many systems of this ilk) and the ability to join.

Comment: Dean I think I understand I cannot fully join unless an email is compromised as I rightfully pointed out to you guys already. Go read my post. but the discoverability of joining is way too easy and it really shouldnt be. It makes no sense but yet again a lot of things I report ends up with the same debate.  I understand you dont have time to fix it.

Comment: Should be invite only not easily discoverable. But I already told you so in the other post.

Comment: @JonH invite only doesn't necessarily scale to large numbers of users; it's a lot of work for the admin(s). Email domain restrictions are a) commonplace and b) easier for admins to work with. Re. not having time to work on it - if we thought it was a genuine security concern it'd already be addressed. We have decided for now that we'll reflect how other systems perform this. It's the admin's choice as to whether they have domain restrictions or invite-only joins.

Comment: _"the questions I keep getting is we have Confluence, we have Jira, we have HipChat, why do we need teams?"_ So, _do you?_ If you need someone else to explain why you need Teams, and can't explain that yourself, this may be a strong indication that you don't.

Answer (score 26):

We already wrote that page, it just in a blog post called ["How to Get Manager Approval to Buy Stack Overflow for Teams"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/02/how-to-get-manager-approval-to-buy-stack-overflow-for-teams/). It covers some ways you can twist the arm of your boss to get a Team.

Ideally, this will be integrated into the `/Teams` page, we just didn't get it in place for the launch. It is however on the list of things to get in place soon.

Comment: Why dont you guys simply add that "Shiny" link I keep talking about to the teams introduction selling page?  So that people can see the "get boss approval link" and click on it?